# Move ButtonType JavaFX in a Dialog

Tags: button, javafx, dialog

I'm working in a `Dialog` in JavaFX , the user  have to insert a keyword in a `textfield` , then have to press a buttontype that I have created like this:

```
 ButtonType find= new ButtonType("Find");
```

Here my problem, the button always stays in the lower right corner of the dialog, so , I want to put where I want. In the case was a button I would solve with a `Pane` and `SetLayoutX`/`SetLayoutY`, but I don't know how to do with `Buttontype`.

Comment: So where do you want to put it?

Comment: Everywhere, specific coordinates, Center , Top right corner,ecc . It doesn't matter where, it's important How..

Comment: Put the button into your favorite layout pane and then put this layout into dialog with `dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(layout);` . On button click do your job and trigger one of buttontypes defined in dialogpane.